# Can Someone Please Clarify Where .env Files Work in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

The documentation for the Python extension for VS Code says that it supports environment variables being set in a `.env` file.
I've read the documentation and various reports on GitHub, but I have not found any clarity on a few things:

1. Do `.env` files work with tasks? My experience says they don't.
2. Do `.env` files work with the integrated terminal? My experience says they don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.env` files are a construct of the Python extension and so do not work in places that VS Code directly controls (e.g. tasks and the terminal). A lot of people use them with the debugger.

Comment: So, just to be sure, the `.env` is only loaded when the Python extension executes some python code? 
My issue is that I'm trying to find a central place where I can define certain constants that are available throughout my project.

Comment: Not yet, but we are hoping to look into it. We have various issues like https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/944 open tracking individual items, but we want to take a thorough view of things and try to come up with a consistent story for people.